# Cannot read packageName from ...\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error in Android Studio when I try to build my project:
Cannot read packageName from ..`\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

I previously migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and the AndroidManifest.xml file is not located at the directory above, it is in:
..\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

When I create the ..`\src\main` directory and copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file into it, I get a list of new errors, see below.
Should I have to create that directory, or is this what is causing the new errors?:

```
..\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:46: error: resource style/MyTheme (aka style/MyTheme) not found.
..\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:57: error: resource string/app_name (aka string/app_name) not found.
..\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:68: error: resource string/app_name (aka string/app_name) not found.
```

I have read the answers on previous questions similar to this, which mainly point to issues with poorly formed xml, or the applicationId in the build.gradle not matching the package in the AndroidManifest.xml, but unfortunately they don't apply in this case.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Create a new project and copy classes and packages. Fastest approach really

Comment: Delete the `/app/build`, `/build` and `/.idea` folders and try again.

Comment: I took your advice and created a new project and added in all classes and xml files and the project is working now. It created a different file structure than when migrated from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From your code i figure out that maybe in your style resource appTheme not defined .So first put this code in your style.xml file.

```
<!-- Base application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

N.B: you also need to define the color in your resource file.

Then also add this code in your resorce file

```
<string name="app_name">your app name</string>
```

Maybe it will help you.